# Jhipster Webpack prod error white sreen

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

I have a Jhipster 4 project and when I try to run mvn -Pprod package the assets are generated inside /target/www, but when I try to run the Angular part of the project I get an white page and the bellow error on the console:

```
"Error: moduleId should be a string in "e". See link for more information.
```

If you're using Webpack you should inline the template and the styles, see link.
    at e.d (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/f747e4dbb5d31963669b.polyfills.bundle.js:50:1731)
    at e [as constructor] (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:1714:420)
    at new e (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:59:749)
    at s (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:305:6242)
    at t._loadDirectiveMetadata (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:312:4000)
    at file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:312:7106
    at Array.forEach ()
    at t.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:312:7078)
    at file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:1105:2432
    at Array.forEach ()
    at t._loadModules (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:1105:2385)
    at t._compileModuleAndComponents (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:1105:1803)
    at t.compileModuleAsync (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:1105:1226)
    at e._bootstrapModuleWithZone (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:762:2664)
    at e.bootstrapModule (file:///C:/Users/Patricia%20Alves/Desktop/delivery/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:762:2289)"

Comment: Which node version `node -v`?

Comment: Node version: v6.9.1